# Build XML literal containing Anti-XML object

Tags: xml, scala, xml-literals, anti-xml

Suppose I have an Anti-XML object, e.g.:

```
import com.codecommit.antixml._
val child = <child attr="val">...</child>.convert
```

I want to construct an XML object that contains `child` as a child:

```
<parent foo="bar"><foo/><child attr="val">...</child><foo/></parent>
```

The obvious way would be

```
val parent : Elem = <parent foo="bar"><foo/>{ child }<foo/></parent>.convert
```

The problem is that Scala's XML literals don't recognize Anti-XML's objects, so `child` gets converted to a string, and embedded in `parent` as a text node:

```
<parent foo="bar"><foo/>&lt;child attr="val"&gt;...&lt;/child&gt;<foo/></parent>
```

How can I work around this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`XML.loadString` should do the trick:

```
val child: com.codecommit.antixml.Elem = <child />.convert
val parent: scala.xml.Elem = <parent>{scala.xml.XML.loadString(child.toString)}</parent>
```

For more complicated scenarios of deep manipulation, I think you would do better by avoiding using literals and using the built in `Zipper` support.